# Subquery with LIMIT in MYSQL complex query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, limit

The Mysql version i'm using don't let me use a LIMIT inside subquery so i can speed up the query. How to use join instead in the next query?

```
SELECT p . * , (

SELECT AVG( review_rating ) AS rating_total
FROM reviews r
WHERE r.review_item_ref = p.pattern_ref
AND r.review_state =1
GROUP BY r.review_item_ref
) AS review_rating
FROM patterns p
WHERE pattern_active >=0
AND p.pattern_family =27
AND p.pattern_ref
IN (

SELECT item_pattern_ref
FROM items
WHERE item_pattern_ref = p.pattern_ref LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY p.pattern_id
ORDER BY p.pattern_description ASC , LCASE( p.pattern_description ) ASC
LIMIT 0 , 16
```

Comment: Consider to post relevant DDL, sample data and desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Brane got what i needed so by now no need to expand my Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to validate that p.pattern_ref has a match in items, is that correct?

If so,

```
SELECT 
    p . *,
    (SELECT AVG( review_rating ) AS rating_total
        FROM reviews r
        WHERE r.review_item_ref = p.pattern_ref
            AND r.review_state =1
        GROUP BY r.review_item_ref
    ) AS review_rating
FROM patterns p
INNER JOIN items i ON p.pattern_ref = i.item_pattern_ref
WHERE p.pattern_active >= 0
    AND p.pattern_family = 27
GROUP BY p.pattern_id
ORDER BY p.pattern_description ASC , LCASE( p.pattern_description ) ASC
LIMIT 0 , 16
```

should work.  INNER JOIN will only return rows where both sides have a match.

Comment: Correct. Thanks. Could you tell why my query without LIMIT 1 needs 26" and yours just 0.008"?

Comment: You're welcome.  I am pretty sure the IN statement is slower than INNER JOIN.  If you like, you can try EXPLAIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIMIT in a subquery.